# Adding a texture causes crash... ( uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException' )

Tags: sprite-kit, xcode8, skspritenode, sktexture, sceneeditor

So I'm working on a side scroller. 
Each level has a Sprite with a Custom Class of Player.
While the texture that determines that sprite is set by it's idle animation, I've applied a texture in each Level for reference.

In each level it seems to work fine

E.g. Here's my level 2 with my main Player Monkey Sprite as it appears in most levels.

[image]

However, on two levels any changes to this Player Sprite causes the game to crash.
I'm forced to leave the thing as an untextured sprite... any kind of change causes the game to crash. For instance if I add a new texture I get the following error.

E.g. Here it must be left untextured or I get a crash.
[image]

```
       *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid size specified: {6, -2.6005233764648423}'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001041a534b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010389e21e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010420e265 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   SpriteKit                           0x0000000104d5060c -[SKSpriteNode initWithTexture:color:size:] + 204
    4   SideScrolleriOS                     0x00000001030248e5 _TFC15SideScrolleriOS8PlatformcfT7textureGSqCSo9SKTexture_5colorCSo7UIColor4sizeVSC6CGSize_S0_ + 661
    5   SideScrolleriOS                     0x00000001030785e6 _TFC15SideScrolleriOS14MovingPlatformcfT7textureGSqCSo9SKTexture_5colorCSo7UIColor4sizeVSC6CGSize_S0_ + 246
    6   SideScrolleriOS                     0x00000001030786e6 _TToFC15SideScrolleriOS14MovingPlatformcfT7textureGSqCSo9SKTexture_5colorCSo7UIColor4sizeVSC6CGSize_S0_ + 86
    7   SpriteKit                           0x0000000104d5157a -[SKSpriteNode initWithColor:size:] + 25
    8   SideScrolleriOS                     0x0000000103026ac4 _TTOFCSo12SKSpriteNodecfT5colorCSo7UIColor4sizeVSC6CGSize_S_ + 36
    9   SideScrolleriOS                     0x000000010301f440 _TFCSo12SKSpriteNodeCfT5colorCSo7UIColor4sizeVSC6CGSize_S_ + 96
    10  SideScrolleriOS                     0x000000010301e9c6 _TFC15SideScrolleriOS8Platform13setUpPlatformfCS_6PlayerT_ + 2166
    11  SideScrolleriOS                     0x0000000103077609 _TFC15SideScrolleriOS14MovingPlatform13setUpPlatformfCS_6PlayerT_ + 73
    12  SideScrolleriOS                     0x00000001030a9b0e _TFC15SideScrolleriOS9GameScene7didMovefT2toCSo6SKView_T_ + 12430
    13  SideScrolleriOS                     0x00000001030b6aaa _TToFC15SideScrolleriOS9GameScene7didMovefT2toCSo6SKView_T_ + 58
    14  SpriteKit                           0x0000000104d12c57 -[SKScene _didMoveToView:] + 198
    15  SpriteKit                           0x0000000104d3152e -[SKView presentScene:transition:] + 364
    16  SideScrolleriOS                     0x000000010309018d _TFC15SideScrolleriOS4Home8loadGamefT_T_ + 13805
    17  SideScrolleriOS                     0x000000010308cb1f _TFC15SideScrolleriOS4Home13pressedSelectfT_T_ + 4159
    18  SideScrolleriOS                     0x0000000103054cff _TFFC15SideScrolleriOS4Home12touchesBeganFTGVs3SetCSo7UITouch_4withGSqCSo7UIEvent__T_U_FTCSo6SKNodeGSpV10ObjectiveC8ObjCBool__T_ + 1375
    19  SideScrolleriOS                     0x0000000103043774 _TTRXFo_oCSo6SKNodedGSpV10ObjectiveC8ObjCBool___XFdCb_dS_dGSpS1____ + 68
    20  SpriteKit                           0x0000000104d4a946 -[SKNode _processSearchTokens:visited:usingBlock:stopPointer:] + 2729
    21  SpriteKit                           0x0000000104d4a083 -[SKNode _processSearchTokens:visited:usingBlock:stopPointer:] + 486
    22  SpriteKit                           0x0000000104d49d3a -[SKNode _enumerateChildNodesWithName:usingBlock:stopPointer:] + 1127
    23  SpriteKit                           0x0000000104d49612 -[SKNode enumerateChildNodesWithName:usingBlock:] + 58
    24  SideScrolleriOS                     0x0000000103054591 _TFC15SideScrolleriOS4Home12touchesBeganfTGVs3SetCSo7UITouch_4withGSqCSo7UIEvent__T_ + 737
    25  SideScrolleriOS                     0x0000000103054e96 _TToFC15SideScrolleriOS4Home12touchesBeganfTGVs3SetCSo7UITouch_4withGSqCSo7UIEvent__T_ + 102
    26  SpriteKit                           0x0000000104d2f6d6 -[SKView touchesBegan:withEvent:] + 1145
    27  UIKit                               0x0000000104feba21 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2043
    28  UIKit                               0x0000000104fed3cf -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4011
    29  UIKit                               0x0000000104f9a63f -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 371
    30  UIKit                               0x000000010578c71d __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3248
    31  UIKit                               0x00000001057853c7 __handleEventQueue + 4879
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010414a311 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010412f59c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010412ea86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010412e494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    36  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000108cb4a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    37  UIKit                               0x0000000104f7c964 UIApplicationMain + 159
    38  SideScrolleriOS                     0x0000000103109ecf main + 111
    39  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010c7c568d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I've tried to fix the error by

1. Duplicating my Level 2 and deleting everything but the Monkey Sprite and Camera (and it's children) , then pasting everything from the problematic level in (except the untextured sprite and it's camera). The error still occurs.

This didn't seem to happen when I was developing the thing in Xcode 7, but the switch to Swift 3 and Xcode 8 has caused some weird errors.

I've tried this for both the problem levels. I can't figure it out. The game build works fine if I just leave it untextured. 
I can add a texture in the scene editor.
But, then the build crashes.

But, it'd be helpful to have the sprite textured for editing reference. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: your texture size is 6, -2.6

Comment: When solving exceptions, pay attention to the part following the "reason" as it says `Invalid size specified: {6, -2.6005233764648423}`. Your texture can't be -2 in height. Maybe there is some piece of code in the class that manages the level that is calculating the size of the texture wrong. You can also set exception breakpoints: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode; and see if that shows you what line the issue might be coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason adding an exception breakpoint didn't reveal the line of code that was causing the issue.

Something in my code was calculating a negative size just as the error said.
**The way I found it was by try copying in the assets little by little from a "bad level" to a working level. 
I did this till the thing crashed.
By doing that I isolated the issue to one asset type.**

Turns out part of my code relied on the sizing of my player texture to calculate something. While this calculation almost never resulted in a negative number... in those two levels it did.
So getting rid of the player texture worked as temporary fix because it prevented the number being negative by not being subtracted.